# Customer complete order setup by admin?

Tags: magento-1.7

(cross-post from stackoverflow, sorry)

I'm exploring implementation options in Magento and am wondering if anyone has attempted or found a solution to this scenario...

I would like to be able to setup an order via the Magento backend (add products, set shipping price, etc) then have the customer be able to complete the order by logging into their account and proceeding through the checkout process.

Would be really great if the customer could get an email notification with a link directly to the payment step/checkout.

Is there a public extension that does this or something similar? Is the only option to push the products to a customer's cart then manually notify? Any other approaches on this?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways of accomplishing this (assuming that all product are enable in that store)

1. In Admin create new order for that customer and add all items to quote, then under 'Items Ordered -> Action' click 'Move to Shopping Cart' (items will disappear from quote and should appear in the customer shopping cart once log in)
   [image]
2. Create a custom quotation module (or modify new order creation)  that email the customer with a link that will restore the quote on so the customer can complete the transaction

*I'm currently creating a quotation module with the same ability for customer to place the order online*

Comment: Looks like a custom quotation module is what I'm looking for, as I would need custom product pricing and custom shipping pricing. Moving to the shopping cart doesn't apply the custom pricing option unfortunately.

Let me know when your module is ready!

Comment: R.S Did you succeed in the custom quotation module?

Comment: 98% complete, few minor things I need to fix but it been in production for over 2yrs.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to emulate the frontend: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/

Then login the user:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerId);
```

And then fetch the cart / create an order.